# More efficient way to search a large matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a code that does what I want but it is too slow because I have a very large mat file with a matrix (33 gigabyte) that I need to search for particular values and extract those.

The file that I'm searching has the following structure:

```
reporter    sector  partner year    ave        
 USA        all     CAN     2007    0.060026126 
 USA        all     CAN     2011    0.0637898418
...
```

This goes on for millions of rows. I want to extract the last (5th) column value for particular reporter and `partner` values (sector and year are fixed). In actuality there are more fixed values that I have taken out for the sake of simplicity but this might slow down my code even more. The `country_codes` and `partner` values need to vary and are looped for that reason.

The crucial part of my code is the following:

```
for i = 1:length(country_codes)
    for g = [1:length(partner)]  
        matrix(i,g) = big_file(...
            ismember(GTAP_data(:,1), country_codes(i)) & ... % reporter
            ismember(GTAP_data(:,2), 'all') & ...sector
            ismember(GTAP_data(:,3), partner(g)) & ...  partner
            ismember([GTAP_data{:,4}]', 2011) & ... year
            ,5); % ave column     
    end
end
```

In other words, the code goes through the million rows and finds just the right value by applying `ismember` with logical `&` on everything.

Is there a faster way to do this than using `ismember`? Can someone assist?

Comment: 1) Could you clarify a bit on the time it takes to run the code atm? How fast can you read from your harddisk? Because in general, 500MB/s, 33GB, it would take about a minute just to open the file.

2) Do you have 33GB of free internal memory?

3) What type of matfile do you use? (4, 6, 7 or 7.3) Is it compressed?

Comment: 1) The code takes on the order of about a day to finish. I'm running this on a Dell xps 15 9530. This has a solid state drive so it should be relatively quick and not terribly bottlenecked. 2) I have 100 gb free disk space. do you think this might be the issue? 3) I use  '-v7.3' and matlab 2014a. I think I set this so that it could handle such a large file.

Comment: Indeed, that could do 500MB/s. Your function `big_file` is not a build in matlab function right? Maybe that can be improved?

Comment: big_file is just how I named the 33 gb large matrix.

Comment: Oke, so before this code there is probably something like `big_file = matfile(filename,'Writable',0);` ?

Comment: it is: big_file = importfile(big_data_file); 
save('GTAP_data.mat', 'GTAP_data', '-v7.3')  load('big_file.mat') the whole code is here fyi: https://github.com/HaukeHillebrandt/CDI-Trade/blob/master/gtap_analysis_script.m note the slightly different naming conventions.

Comment: This seems like a good use case for `datastore`. Once you create the `TabularTextDatastore` you can use the `read` method to read chunks of records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So what I see is you build a big table out of the data in different files.

It seems your values are text-based. That takes up more memory. "USA" already takes up three bytes of memory. If you have less then 255 countries to concider, you could store them as only one byte in uint8 format.

If you can store all columns as a value between 0 and 255 you can make a uint8 matrix that can be indexed very fast.

As an example:

```
%demo
GTAP_regions={'USA','NL','USA','USA','NL','GB','NL','USA','Korea Republic of','GB','NL','USA','Korea Republic of'};
S=whos('GTAP_regions');
S.bytes
```

`GTAP_regions` requires 1580 bytes. Now we convert it.

```
GTAP_regions_list=GTAP_regions(1);
GTAP_regions_uint=uint8(1);
for ct = 2:length(GTAP_regions)
    I=ismember(GTAP_regions_list,GTAP_regions(ct));
    if ~any(I)
        GTAP_regions_list(end+1)=GTAP_regions(ct);
    else
        GTAP_regions_uint(end+1)=uint8(find(I));
    end
end

S=whos('GTAP_regions_list');
S.bytes
S=whos('GTAP_regions_uint');
S.bytes
```

`GTAP_regions_uint` we need to use to do indexing, and it is now only 10 bytes and will be very fast to analyse.

`GTAP_regions_list` we need to use to find what index value belongs to what country, is only 496 bytes.

You can also do this for sector, partner and year, depending on the range of years. If it is no more than 255 different years it will work. Otherwise you could store it as uint16 and have 65535 possible options.